# Ruby Gemfile can not add the PostgreSQL gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

#my added gems
gem 'pg', '~> 0.17.1'
gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

You can see on the 4th line that I add the line for the `pg` gem. After saving and running `bundle install` in my terminal I get the following error with this error:

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try before bundle install what the message says?

```
 gem install pg -v '0.17.1'
```

Also, If you are running this locally and you need postrgre just to deploy the app to a server like Heroku(you are using sqlite/mysql locally) add it to the production enviroment like this:

```
 group :production do
   gem 'pg'
 end
```

and run

```
   bundle install
```

again.

Comment: oh, i misread my tutorial, i wasn't supposed to install these gems locally. makes sense. thank you.